# How to block specific ip address while being attacked by hping3?

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall

I am working on a project of cybersecurity and I am sending from Kali Linux an attack to an Ubuntu VM with the following command:

```
sudo hping3 -c 15000 -d 300 -w 64 -p 22 --flood 192.168.40.40
```

I have tried almost all configuration of iptables to block the ip that I am sending the attack (`192.168.40.55`), i.e., I have tried commands similar as following :

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.40.55 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.40.55 -j DROP
...
```

But the attack doesn't block, because we can see the packets with a ip traffic software.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

This is my output of `iptables-save -c`:

[image]

**New edit:**

Data from the VM I am attacking:
[image]

**New edit:**
[image]

Comment: FYI your packet analysis will still show the packets, those aren't filtered out at the packet sniffer level.  The question is are you getting responses back.  Does your system return the recho requests?  Share the output of `iptables-save -c` as well to show us the rules in place on yoru system.

Comment: You are appending your iptables rule, but you might need to insert it as a lower numbered rule. i.e. try `iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 192.168.40.55 -j DROP` As per the previous comment, we need to see your rule set to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks to both, I have edited my question, hope you can help me.

Comment: @DannyHern HOw are  you 'seeing the traffic' in IP Traffic Software?  Do you mean Wireshark?  Wireshark listens directly on the interface *before* it even hits the `iptables` rules so you will still see packets.  If you see no *response* packets being sent in response to the packets that are being sent to the machine then `iptables` is working.

Comment: @ThomasWard, Thanks Thomas. I am using metricbeat, I am not seeing the iptraffic exactly, I am monitoring the data of the virtual machine I am attacking. I am using metricbeat, a software of Elastic (https://www.elastic.co/es/products/beats/metricbeat). And I use a machine learning model for anomaly detection that uses the data from metricbeat. (See the new image).

Comment: What I want to do is to block any connection from the ip 192.168.40.55. It doesn't matter how to do it!

Comment: @DannyHern Without knowing how that software works I can't really help you out here, I'd talk to them.  Likely they're relying on a `tcpdump` or similar tool to monitor the actual packet flow in/out of the box.  You'll have to either `tcpdump` or Wireshark this to see the actual packet flow in your environment and see if you're only seeing inbound connections or if you're receiving an actual response to the packets.

Comment: @DannyHern Which the iptables counters *show* you're doing already

Comment: @ThomasWard, I just see "in packets". This software is similar to wireshark. Please, see the new image and you'll see just in packets. The image I am showing is without apply iptable commands. With the iptable commands it's the same

Comment: As i **just stated**, your software listens BEFORE `iptables` comes into play.  That is, at the interface level BEFORE it even reaches the kernel’s TCP/IP processing/stack which `iptables` then comes into play at.  You will ***ALWAYS*** see inbound packets coming to your machine when listening at the interface level.  `iptables` cannot block those at the link level.  You need to implement **upstream** filtering on a box in between your packet origin systems and the destination, basically a NAT gateway or transparent firewall to prescreen packets, to hide them from the final endpoint listener.

Answer (score 1):

Your method to test and demonstrate the functionality of your iptables rules will not work. Your hping3 generated packets do not have the SYN bit set, and therefore ultimately get DROPed, either by iptables rule or because nothing else knows what to do with it either.

If you modify your hping3 command to include the SYN flag, and if you have `sshd` listening to port 22, you will get a reply, and have the starting conditions for a test. Example (in my case 192.268.111.112 is running hping3 against 192.168.111.122)(I slowed things down also):

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo hping3 -c 5 -d 300 -w 64 -p 22 --syn --interval 5 s18
HPING s18 (br0 192.168.111.122): S set, 40 headers + 300 data bytes
len=46 ip=192.168.111.122 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=22 flags=SA seq=0 win=64240 rtt=1.9 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.111.122 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=22 flags=SA seq=1 win=64240 rtt=1.8 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.111.122 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=22 flags=SA seq=2 win=64240 rtt=1.7 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.111.122 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=22 flags=SA seq=3 win=64240 rtt=1.6 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.111.122 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=22 flags=SA seq=4 win=64240 rtt=1.5 ms

--- s18 hping statistic ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.5/1.7/1.9 ms
doug@s15:~$
```

Over on the destination computer I had tcpdump running. Observe the tcp connection beging created via SYN and SYN ACK handshake. hping3 then resets the connection, whereas bad guys might not.

```
doug@s18:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i enp3s0 host 192.168.111.112
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2020-01-08 14:09:38.393919 IP 192.168.111.112.2728 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 1675527679:1675527979, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:09:38.393980 IP 192.168.111.122.22 > 192.168.111.112.2728: Flags [S.], seq 1494575109, ack 1675527680, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:38.394213 IP 192.168.111.112.2728 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [R], seq 1675527680, win 0, length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:43.394019 IP 192.168.111.112.2729 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 1382198395:1382198695, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:09:43.394068 IP 192.168.111.122.22 > 192.168.111.112.2729: Flags [S.], seq 3357751063, ack 1382198396, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:43.394318 IP 192.168.111.112.2729 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [R], seq 1382198396, win 0, length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:48.394156 IP 192.168.111.112.2730 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 2046908564:2046908864, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:09:48.394204 IP 192.168.111.122.22 > 192.168.111.112.2730: Flags [S.], seq 922870032, ack 2046908565, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:48.394457 IP 192.168.111.112.2730 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [R], seq 2046908565, win 0, length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:53.394252 IP 192.168.111.112.2731 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 2005387083:2005387383, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:09:53.394307 IP 192.168.111.122.22 > 192.168.111.112.2731: Flags [S.], seq 1168444666, ack 2005387084, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:53.394547 IP 192.168.111.112.2731 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [R], seq 2005387084, win 0, length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:58.394361 IP 192.168.111.112.2732 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 1346771824:1346772124, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:09:58.394415 IP 192.168.111.122.22 > 192.168.111.112.2732: Flags [S.], seq 1213532639, ack 1346771825, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
2020-01-08 14:09:58.394651 IP 192.168.111.112.2732 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [R], seq 1346771825, win 0, length 0
```

Anyway, do the test again, but this time introduce the iptables rule during the hping3 command. Notice the replies stop. I only did one of the two methods you used, `sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.111.112 -j DROP` :

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo hping3 -c 5 -d 300 -w 64 -p 22 --syn --interval 5 s18
HPING s18 (br0 192.168.111.122): S set, 40 headers + 300 data bytes
len=46 ip=192.168.111.122 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=22 flags=SA seq=0 win=64240 rtt=1.9 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.111.122 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=22 flags=SA seq=1 win=64240 rtt=1.8 ms

--- s18 hping statistic ---
5 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 60% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.8/1.8/1.9 ms
doug@s15:~$
```

And on the tcpdump side, notice the reply packets stop:

```
doug@s18:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i enp3s0 host 192.168.111.112
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2020-01-08 14:21:53.046185 IP 192.168.111.112.2218 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 1908410534:1908410834, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:21:53.046228 IP 192.168.111.122.22 > 192.168.111.112.2218: Flags [S.], seq 4143478207, ack 1908410535, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
2020-01-08 14:21:53.046441 IP 192.168.111.112.2218 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [R], seq 1908410535, win 0, length 0
2020-01-08 14:21:58.046251 IP 192.168.111.112.2219 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 1400121544:1400121844, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:21:58.046289 IP 192.168.111.122.22 > 192.168.111.112.2219: Flags [S.], seq 1009904372, ack 1400121545, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
2020-01-08 14:21:58.046512 IP 192.168.111.112.2219 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [R], seq 1400121545, win 0, length 0
2020-01-08 14:22:03.046326 IP 192.168.111.112.2220 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 628135359:628135659, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:22:08.046392 IP 192.168.111.112.2221 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 836315746:836316046, win 64, length 300
2020-01-08 14:22:13.046523 IP 192.168.111.112.2222 > 192.168.111.122.22: Flags [S], seq 1462266142:1462266442, win 64, length 300
```

And we can also observe the packet counters in the iptables rule set. 3 packets dropped after 2 had been replied to, total 5, which is what was sent:

```
doug@s18:~$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 27 packets, 2784 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       3     1020 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.111.112      0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 1272 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Thank you Doug, what rules of iptables did you apply?

Comment: @DannyHern : `sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.111.112 -j DROP`